# Pull to refresh not working with firebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to use swipe down to refresh in my activity. My activity is synced with Firebase Database and I am using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to get all the data in a recycler from my firebase account. However my app is not showing anything. Even swipe action is not generating any animation.

MainAcitivty.java

```
package com.example.admin.eventadmin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView r_event_list;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Event");

        r_event_list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.request_EventList);
        r_event_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        r_event_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               refreshItems();
            }
        });

    }
    public void refreshItems(){
        loadItems();
    }


    public void loadItems(){

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder>(
                Event.class,
                R.layout.event_list_row,
                RequestViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(RequestViewHolder viewHolder, Event model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setCategory(model.getCategory());
                viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
                viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setImageUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageUrl());

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                final String title = model.getTitle();
                final String desc = model.getDesc();
                final String image = model.getImageUrl();
                final String category = model.getCategory();
                final String price = model.getPrice();
                final String location = model.getLocation();

                final DatabaseReference aRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                viewHolder.verify_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Approving Event");
                        progressDialog.show();
                        String key = aRef.child("Approved Events").push().getKey();
                        Event event = new Event(title, image, price, category, location, desc);

                        Map<String, Object> eventValues = event.toMap();

                        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                        childUpdates.put("/ApprovedEvents/" + key, eventValues);

                        aRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        r_event_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public Button verify_button;


        public RequestViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            verify_button = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.approve_button);

        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView request_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_title);
            request_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView request_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_desc);
            request_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            TextView request_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_location);
            request_desc.setText(location);
        }

        public void setCategory(String category) {
            TextView request_category = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_category);
            request_category.setText(category);
        }
        public void setPrice(String price) {
            TextView request_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_price);
            request_price.setText(price);
        }

        public void setImageUrl(Context ctx, String imageUrl) {
            ImageView request_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageUrl).into(request_image);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.eventadmin.MainActivity">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/request_EventList"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why is android-studio removed as a tag for this question ??@RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: You may be using Android Studio, but the question is not related to it. Questions should be tagged with topics that are relevant to the question, not based on the project you're building/tools you're using. Otherwise we'd end up tagging every question with "compiler" too. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Haha ok , I got your point :) Will keep it in my mind next time.

Comment: @rut_0_1 : you don't need to use SwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 7):

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter never requires a "pull to refresh" operation.  It is always in sync with the data in the database.  If something changes in the database, it will be automatically reflected in the adapter, as long as you have a network connection.

You should just assume that FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is always showing the most recent data and don't bother with pull to refresh when using it.

Comment: Few concerns: Does it scale say for a hundreds of new item loaded to firebase within lifecycle of the activity? Are you using it in production inplace of traditional pull to refesh ? Is it possible to throw up an user interrupt like a floating "load new items" buttion and refresh only after user taps that ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 That's a lot of questions in one small comment.  Why don't you post your questions to firebase-talk instead?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve this using **yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look a this page -> https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/respond-refresh-request.html.

I think this are the relevent code lines, that you need to implement into your code.

```
// Signal SwipeRefreshLayout to start the progress indicator
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
// Start the refresh background task.
// This method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
myUpdateOperation();
```